# Log4Net not writing all entries before application exits

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using Log4Net with a programatic configuration as shown below.
One of my customers has noticed that some log entries are randomly not writing. Is it possible that Log4Net doesnt write all log entries before the application exits?

Below is a simplified example usage of Log4Net that i am using in my application. As far as i can see it should either write the Success, Failure or Exception but the customer randomly doesnt see the result line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LogConfig.Setup();
    LogInstance = LogManager.GetLogger("Application");        

    try
    {
        bool Success = DoStuff();

        if(Success)
             LogInstance.Info("Success");
        else
             LogInstance.Info("Failure");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         LogInstance.Info("Exception");
    }
}


public class LogConfig
{
    public static void Setup()
    {
        Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();

        PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
        patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
        patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

        RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
        roller.AppendToFile = false;
        roller.File = @"Logs\EventLog.txt";
        roller.Layout = patternLayout;
        roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 21;
        roller.MaximumFileSize = "1GB";
        roller.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
        roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
        roller.ActivateOptions();
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);

        MemoryAppender memory = new MemoryAppender();
        memory.ActivateOptions();
        
        hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(memory);

        hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
        hierarchy.Configured = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Fildor Yes your right, ive updated the answer. Just a typo in writing sample code in the stack overflow website.

Comment: Try set "ImmediateFlush=true" on the rolling appender

Comment: @PatrickTshibanda The default value of the appender for ImmediateFlush is true. Im not changing it so it is already true.

Comment: Is your customer correct in the first place? Have you seen and checked example LogFiles from them out of production?

Comment: @Fildor Yes ive seen the logs. Doesnt happen on my system however. I guess its just a race between logging and the application exiting. Ive added LogManager.Shutdown(); as the last entry in the main method to see if that resolves it.

Comment: Put it in `finally`... just in case.